# Python memory leaks using Bokeh library for plotting

Tags: python, memory, bokeh

I have a function, that at first reads the data from external files and then plot it using bokeh. The problem is, that if I use the function several times, it consumes a bit memory every time, so after a while the memory is full. By memory I mean the memory used by python, not the browser showing the graph. The following code is plotting the data inside the function.

```
w=self.time_diff_calc(time_diff.split("_")[0]+time_diff.split("_")[1])*60*500
colors=["#C93434","#78AD32","#5E6069","#9651DB","","","","","","","","","","",""]

#mids- middle of candlestick, span- height
mids = np.array((data1["open"] + data1["close"])/2)
spans = np.array(abs(data1["close"]-data1["open"]))

#inc- open<close, dec- open>close
inc = data1["close"]>data1["open"]
dec = data1["close"]<data1["open"]

##############the part that eats the memory###################

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime",plot_width=1200)

data_time=data1["time"]
data_high=data1["high"]
data_low=data1["low"]

p.segment(data_time, data_high, data_time, data_low, color="black")

data_inc=data_time[inc]
data_dec=data_time[dec]
mids_inc=mids[inc]
mids_dec=mids[dec]
spans_inc=spans[inc]
spans_dec=spans[dec]

p.rect(data_inc,mids_inc , w, spans_inc, fill_color="#58AFD1", line_color="black")
p.rect(data_dec, mids_dec, w, spans_dec, fill_color="#FFFFFF", line_color="black")

###########################################################

p.title=self.name
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
save(p)
```

Comment: Do you mean more memory is being used by the python process that creates the plots? Or by a browser process that is displaying the plots?

Comment: I've edited the question.. I meant memory used by python

Comment: I am having the same issue. I was able to trace it. [Bokeh Memory Leak Graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ZbH.png)
This is the output from objgraph: Timestamp 552511 +75610 dict 65030 +6620 list 46936 +4895 tuple 42418 +3247 set 16205 +1880 BlockPlacement 11650 +1542 PropertyValueList 10146 +1340 Series 9514 +1260 SingleBlockManager 9514 +1260 IntBlock 4077 +540 This is the graph of the leak.